# Drupal theme to Joomla Template

Tags: drupal, joomla

I have a drupal theme and would like to use it on a Joomla site. Is there a way to do this please because from what I searched online, you can only from joomla to drupal and not the other way round

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you want to pay a developer or a company to redevelop the theme. Drupal's API and Joomla's aren't similar or interchangeable.

Short answer: there isn't an easy way.